# Installing qTox from repository without tee -q0

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu

I wanted to install Tox ( http://tox.chat ) on my Xubuntu 16.04.
Main site suggest adding repository this way:

```
echo "deb https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly $(lsb_release -cs)" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list
wget -qO - https://pkg.tox.chat/debian/pkg.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

but running it gives me error:

```
tee: invalid option -- 'q'
Try 'tee --help' for more information.
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I have checked "man tee" and indeed, tee does not offer -q option.
I know, that wget has it, however so I have tried this way:

```
echo deb https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly $(lsb_release -cs) | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list $(wget -qO - https://pkg.tox.chat/debian/pkg.gpg.key) | sudo apt-key add -
tee: unrecognized option '-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----'
Try 'tee --help' for more information.
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I also know, that I can install qTox from .deb package, but I prefer to keep it always updated/synchronized with repository.

How can I install qTox from repository?

Side question: why does tox or any other software provide scripts like this to add repository instead of offering such simple approach like "apt-add-repository ppa:user/repository"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/antonbatenev:/tox/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install qtox
```

Comment: I had to add --allow-unauthenticated to apt-get install, but yes, it works.
Could You explain, why commands from main website didn't work, but this did, please?